# How to bind an object to a button - ASP.NET (C# Tag property equivalent)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am creating an asp.net Point of Sale system. On my form, I am using AJAX tab container to dynamically populate all my products from my database as buttons.

```
private void AddProductsToTab()
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp in TabContainer1.Tabs)
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)rdb).ObjectContext; //we cast our database to an object context, so we can use it in the ObjectQuery.
        ObjectQuery<tblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P WHERE P.ProductType = " + i.ToString(),objectContext);
        foreach (tblProduct tprod in filteredProduct)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Height = 100;
            b.Width=100;
            b.Text = tprod.Description;
            tp.Controls.Add(b);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

For my database, I am using code first entity framework, hence I have my DB entities as classes (class tblProduct). I have a list box, and would like when a product button from the tab container is clicked, to have that products name and price to be displayed on the list box.

In C#, when I am creating the button I could use the (in my case) b.Tag property to put my object (product) into the button and then use a click event for it. But in asp.net, a "Tag" property does not exist on the button. How could I overcome this? Could I somehow just used databind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set products name and price to data attribute of your button. When a product button is clicked, you could use jQuery to get products name and price from data attribute of this button and display it on the list box.

```
private void AddProductsToTab()
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp in TabContainer1.Tabs)
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)rdb).ObjectContext; //we cast our database to an object context, so we can use it in the ObjectQuery.
        ObjectQuery<tblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P WHERE P.ProductType = " + i.ToString(),objectContext);
        foreach (tblProduct tprod in filteredProduct)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Height = 100;
            b.Width=100;
            b.Text = tprod.Description;
            b.CssClass = "product-button";
            b.Attributes["data-name"] = tprod.Name;
            b.Attributes["data-price"] = tprod.Price;
            tp.Controls.Add(b);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

At client side, you could access name and price information of a product like this

```
$(".product-button").on("click", function(e) {
     var button = $(e.currentTarget);
     var productName = button.data("name");
     var productPrice = button.data("price");
     // ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give you feedback as soon as I assimilate and try this, since I am relatively new to jQuery.